# Check if object is from certain package

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to check if an object's class is from a certain package?

Like, when I check if an object is of a certain class using `instanceof`,
I want something similar to check for a package in Java.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check using

```
myInstance.getClass().getPackage()
```

Comment: no parsing
I found a method myInstance.getClass().getPackage().getName()

Answer (score 9):

```
if (instanceofClass.getClass().getPackage().getName().equals("packageyouwanttocheck")) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how you can do that.

```
package my.packaging.name;

class X {
}

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String packageName = "my.packaging.name";
        X x = new X();
        if (x.getClass().getPackage().getName().equals(packageName)) {
            System.out.println("x belongs to package my.packaging.name");
        } else {
            System.out.println("x does not belong to package my.packaging.name");
        }
    }
}
```